# need help with this differential equation problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{( x^3.y^2 - y +x)}{x}$

so i tried with all the methods bit it just doesn't convert to exact ode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Start using $y=\frac vx $ which makes the equation $$\frac{v'}{x}-v^2-1=0$$ which is quite simple $$\frac {v'}{v^2+1}=x$$ Integrate both sides.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{( x^3.y^2 - y +x)}{x}$$
$$xdy=( x^3.y^2 - y +x)dx$$
$$xdy+ydx=(x^3y^2+x)dx$$
$$d(xy)=x(x^2y^2+1)dx$$
$$\dfrac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2+1}=xdx$$
$$\arctan(xy)=\dfrac12x^2+C$$